# How to force Jetty to use IPv4

Tags: java, networking, jetty

I am using standalone jetty 9.1.5 to deploy a java webapp.
I want jetty to use IPv4 instead of IPv6 but I cannot manage to do it!
When I type `netstat -tnlp` I can see the following result:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:554           :::*                    LISTEN      27535/java
```

... So that tells me jetty is using IPv6 even when on my `jetty-http.xml` file I have:

```
<Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host"  default="127.0.0.1" /></Set>
```

I am also starting jetty with the following java options:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses
```

... but to no avail; Jetty keeps using IPv6 and I have not been able to force it to use IPv4.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java is making the decision to use IPv4 or IPv6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/), not Jetty.

Jetty 9.1.5 is very old, consider upgrading to at least the Jetty 9.2.x series.

The example `127.0.0.1:554` is not an IPv6 Local Address, something is off with your netstat output.

Specify the `jetty.host` in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`, do not edit the `jetty-http.xml`.

> Important Note: Do not edit, change, delete, rename, move, etc any content in your `${jetty.home}`.  Specify your configuration in your `${jetty.base}`.

Did you try to connect to your running server using `127.0.0.1:554`? (it will probably work)

If you don't want Java to default to IPv6, then the java command line option would look like this ...

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

However, if you don't have an IPv4 stack on your machine (such as not having a network interface with an IPv4 address, which is a surprisingly common setup), then this java command line option/argument is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Turns out I added the ```-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true``` on the JAVA_OPTIONS of ```${jetty.base}/bin/jetty.sh``` startup script and that had no effect. When I modified JAVA_OPTIONS on ```${jetty.base}/start.ini``` then it worked. Could you let let me know why?